# Unable To Put Error Message in Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like my error message to appear in my label (`lblNewTemperature`) however, every time I use the format `lblNewTemperature.Text = "Error message"`, it doesn't work, and messes with my overall code. Any idea as to why this may be happening?

```
if (!double.TryParse(txtTemperature.Text, out inputTemperature))  // Checking that user input is valid
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");  // Error message that is displayed
            txtTemperature.ResetText();  // Resets the form
            txtTemperature.Focus();  // Places the user's cursor back in the Temperature textbox
        }
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, or what the problem is. Also  `it doesn't work, and messes with my overall code` is not a valid description of a problem. what error message do you get?

Comment: I just assumed that maybe I was putting the error message in the wrong place... I don't get an error message when I use `lblNewTemperature.Text`, instead, it calculates the temperature conversion of 0 degrees Celsius to Fahrenheit for some reason.

Comment: When parsing fails, inputTemperature is set to 0. You probably continue the code but should return instead after the Focus. But without the whole code it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: The condition (if) is failing, that's the reason why.